# WildFly 13 web app not showing login form

Tags: java, servlets, wildfly, jboss5.x

I'm currently migrating an app from JBoss 5 to WildFly 13.
The app consists of an EAR that packs a series of ejbs into a jar and several WAR files holding web apps.

One of the web apps' web.xml looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>

    <display-name>My App</display-name>

    <!-- RESTful web services support -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.test.Dispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- order of security-constraint in web.xml is very important!!! -->
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Secure Content</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>

        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>LOGON</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>

        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>      
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <description>automatic generated role</description>
        <role-name>LOGON</role-name>
    </security-role>

</web-app>
```

The jboss-web only defines the security realm that I have configured:

```xml
    <jboss-web>
      <security-domain>myRealm</security-domain>
    </jboss-web>
```

For all it's worth, due to the I would have expected that the BASIC auth method would prompt the browser login form to show up when I'm calling any resource.

The security subsystem defines a custom security domain, named myRealm, that uses jdbc queries:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:2.0">
    <security-domains>
        <security-domain name="myRealm" cache-type="default">
            <authentication>
                <login-module code="com.login.LoginModule" flag="required" module="org.jboss.login">
                    <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/datasourceDSXA"/>
                    <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA"/>
                    <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="BASE64"/>
                    <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT ...."/>
                    <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT ...."/>
                    <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
                </login-module>
                <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                    <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                </login-module>
            </authentication>
        </security-domain>
</subsystem>
```

The undertow security domain is set to my custom one:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:6.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="myRealm">
```

Ideas on what I might be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `<url-pattern>*</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` did the trick.